# How to run php unit tests in Yii 1.1

Tags: php, unit-testing, yii

Please help. I've been at this for days.

PHPUnit version: 4.4.0

Whenever I try to run a unit test, I get this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'CException' with message 'CHttpRequest is unable to determine the request URI.' in /var/www/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php:519

My bootstrap file:

```
// change the following paths if necessary
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/var/www/protected/config/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium');
$yiit=dirname(__FILE__).'/../../framework/yiit.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/test.php';

require_once($yiit);
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/WebTestCase.php');

Yii::createWebApplication($config);
```

The error Stack trace:

```
#0 /vagrant/black-box/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php(431): CHttpRequest->getRequestUri()
#1 /vagrant/black-box/framework/web/CUrlManager.php(364): CHttpRequest->getPathInfo()
#2 /vagrant/black-box/protected/extensions/yii-debug-toolbar/YiiDebugToolbarRoute.php(113): CUrlManager->parseUrl(Object(CHttpRequest))
#3 /vagrant/black-box/framework/logging/CLogRouter.php(66): YiiDebugToolbarRoute->init()
#4 /vagrant/black-box/framework/base/CModule.php(387): CLogRouter->init()
#5 /vagrant/black-box/framework/base/CModule.php(523): CModule->getComponent('log')
#6 /vagrant/black-box/framework/base/CApplication.php(164): CModule->preloadComponents()
#7 /vagrant/black-box/framework/YiiBase.php(125): CApplication->__construct('/vagrant/black-...')
#8 /vagrant/black-box/framework/YiiBase.php(98): YiiBase::createApplication('CWebApplication', '/vagrant/blac in /vagrant/black-box/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php on line 519
```

Comment: 1. PHPUnit 4 does not work well with Yii 1, try PHPUnit 3.7 instead
2. how are you running the tests?
3. what is the stack trace of the error?

Comment: @bridgeburner Do you want to run only unit tests or unit and functional tests (with selenium)? Check similar questions on this topic here http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[yii]+selenium

Comment: @bridgeburner Can you run unit tests included with yii setup package (demos/blog sample app)?

Comment: @cebe I've downgraded to phpunit 3.7.32, but I still get the error listed above. I'm running the tests by calling phpunit.phar unit/MyTestClass.php. Stack trace for the error: http://pastebin.com/zdbPjEmT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have configured the `YiiDebugToolbarRoute` in your configuration.
This is only useful in web environment and causes problems here.

Remove the configuration for logging from your application config in test ENV.